# Enforcing types of interface value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Working on learning Typescript and am trying to understand how to enforce types based on an interface.

I have this bit of code

```
    interface User{
    name:string;
    age:number;
    friends:string[]
    hasPet:boolean
}

function setValue<T>(key:keyof T, value: T[keyof T] ):void{
    console.log(key, value)
    // ...some additonal logic
}

setValue<User>("age", true )  //should throw error but doesn't
```

I want this interface to enforce the key type when I call `setValue`.   This mostly works, but I can pass any of the available User types into set value.

What I expect is that passing when "age" as the first argument to `setValue`, the 2nd argument should be restricted to the type of "number".  Same for all the other User keys as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is the relevant part of docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints

Comment: Can you explain why you want to specify `User` manually?  What can a function that is generic in `T` like that actually do without a value of type `T`?  You really need the function to be generic in `K extends keyof T`, but I can't tell if you actually need `T` to be generic or if it can be hardcoded as `User`.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mx5pBW) for various options and let me know which if any of those you'd like as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz  The function doesn't have to be generic, that bit was an experiment as I'm trying to learn TS.  I think your `HardcodedUserType` works as I would expect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you want to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `key` input.  Let's alter your example so that it only works for setting properties of `User`, and make a `user` of that type to modify with the function:

```
const user: User = {
  name: "",
  age: 0,
  friends: [],
  hasPet: false
}

function setUserValue<K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: User[K]) {
  user[key] = value;
}
```

Here you can see that the function is generic in `K` which has been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof User`.  The `key` input is of type `K`, and the `value` input is of type `User[K]`, an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) meaning "the property type of `User` at a key of type `K`".  Let's see how it works:

```
setUserValue("age", true); // error, boolean isn't a number 
setUserValue("age", 25) // okay
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers `K` to be the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"age"` and then wants `value` to be of type `User["age"]` which is `number`.

This is the end of the simple version of the answer.

---

That was the standard solution to this problem; do note that it is still possible to do unsafe things with this function, although they are less likely.  For example, when `key` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), things can go wrong:

```
const key = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "age" : "hasPet";
setUserValue(key, true); // no error!  But this has a 50% chance of doing something bad
```

There is currently no direct way in TypeScript to say that we want `K` to be *exactly one* element from the `keyof User` union and not allow it to be a union type itself. There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) asking for support for that. Right now you need to accept `key` being a union (or prevent it in a complicated way I won't get into here).

The real problem is that indexed access types `T[K]` are only safe for *reading* properties, because `T[K1 | K2]` becomes `T[K1] | T[K2]`.  But for *writing* you really want `T[K1 | K2]` to be treated like `T[K1] & T[K2]`... that is, unions in the key type should become [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) in the "writing indexed access" type.

You can express such a type function in TypeScript as follows:

```
type WritingIdx<T, K extends keyof T> =
  { [P in K]: (x: T[P]) => void }[K] extends (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

(Here I'm using essentially the same technique as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to turn unions to intersections)

And then you could declare `setUserValue()` to have `value` be of type `WritingIdx<User, K>` instead of `User[K]`:

```
function setUserValue<K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: WritingIdx<User, K>): void;
function setUserValue<K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: User[K]) {
  user[key] = value;
}
```

Note that I had to make this a one-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) because one drawback of `WritingIdx<User, K>` is that the compiler cannot verify that `user[key] = value` is safe when `value` is of that type.  So inside the implementation I'm widening it to `User[K]`.

Let's check it out:

```
setUserValue("age", true); // error, boolean isn't a number 
setUserValue("age", 25) // okay
setUserValue(key, true); //error!
```

If we imagine that `User` had some property with overlapping types:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  shoeSize: string | number;
}
```

Here `shoeSize` can be either `string` or `number`, but `name` can only be a `string`.  Then `setUserValue()` on both of them should only accept the intersection, which is `string`:

```
const nameOrShoeSize = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "name" : "shoeSize"
setUserValue(nameOrShoeSize, "hasToBeAString"); // okay
setUserValue(nameOrShoeSize, 123); // error
```

So, do you *need* this more complicated version of the answer?  Probably not, if the `key` parameter is only ever going to be a string literal.  Even if unions show up sometimes, you might not want to spend the energy dealing with a complex and pedantic code base.  TypeScript generally [allows unsafe things in the name of developer convenience](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), so there are many other "holes" in the type system.  But I figured I'd at least talk about the issues involved with a generic property writer function.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDc+yct5hArsQEbSMEw0IIACboKVGiFoBtALp9kACzjoAChDAUuAe20AbCHBAL0i7RADKwAF5sJdZAB8O3XrgC+uBNpBVk7TCgKDCwAXhwmIlIKACIYgBomFjYABkT+QRExZDl0pRV1TWR4PUw803MrW1iATgB1GI9cZph2EAQwYB9KDRCoADU4PXYIAB4AaWQIAA9ILOQAawgAT20YNECAPgAKJeWKcfjkADchkeDA6XHZAEoIggDoaT3ZZHDT4YhGT1xMMD7Bp9tjFkglkNQRjd6MgAPQwqZQKDaKBHHT6QwgZDAdAgADkYGYLh4UGQv16gUBI2BoKOACYAKx3OHIbQLODLZpeHx+PZvZAAWTgYEUADooEZhNpiNs7qNkCkRfTkAB+ZAg1gxZCxZRqDQxRh-AFnCC7FZHCEQKGw+EgbQIpFQACEBAAQuwCcLsfl0IT6SkAKTIBDKdooNbISUOdBSjSKBxcODCZpRCDoAAOiBQFjgMGg-Wg6C6mLwTDAyzTKDqNE6UgAksJpqMACpHSYzOaiRYrcNNzZvJgEbA5VRYzHXCjbaYUJvSVS3N5947aYDCZDuK6vdtCTuTiigXMk2t3UKL5er1W1rWECDHNxMVrtTrdQ0U40TKazbc+vbhvo7PYHEcHznMgVbADWtD1o2fStpsNwUEuK4KA+HRFj0-yvp875bvMP7rH+pr7MghwnMaFxPNcdx4AQDyXC8fLAV8TA-EwL55sa1IauaUCQtCzLQA6qK6AYRhYji+KEiAnDEqSBBsQMHHqhAYIMky8KsuyrHkuxQJ7NxvHWgJyKOs0BAwgAVKOkCwJmGxYNRNEpuI1B0AoBDJBQUmuFAbnFJkojOZIMjyAO3qFFowkYr5FSWDYdguVIThEm4BDuMg5kwqZQbcgSKYAPJQBYZixbYfKCsKYoSlKMrIHKCpKqqMQppqsQxVUylaRhOlUvlhXFe1RwxDqTbaC6EAAIIWAltAxFazIaRycnaQpQK9UVlRxUcACMtIAMxzfCRlQM07hAA)

Answer (score 2):

You should inspect this in Typescript playground. The reason it's not throwing an error `keyof` returns a type representing all the properties keys.

So your function actually looks like:

`setValue(key: keyof User, value: string | number | boolean | string[])`

Obviously, what you're trying to do fits one of those types.

Where as if you tried to do something like:

```
let newUser: User;
newUser.age = 'abc'; // Type error
```

Comment: I think I realize that the `keyof` operator is returning all of the available types.  I can't figure out how to narrow the possible type of the 2nd argument with the value of the 1st argument.

Answer (score 2):

For correct type inference, the key must also be a type variable.

Let me guess, but in a real application, you will most likely have a function like

```
function setValue<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]) {
    obj[key] = value;
}

const user: User = {
    name: 'Den',
    age: 22,
    friends: ['1'],
    hasPet: true,
};

setValue(user, 'age', true); // Error - Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```

Because in your example, the function has parameters for the key and value, but there is no object to change.

---

Another alternative solution if you need a setter function for some reason:

```
const createValueSetter = <T>(obj: T) => <K extends keyof T>(
    key: K,
    value: T[K]
) => {
    obj[key] = value;
};

const user: User = {
    name: 'Den',
    age: 2,
    friends: ['1'],
    hasPet: true,
};

const userSetter = createValueSetter(user);

userSetter('age', true); // Error - Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```